# How to select items from an array in sequence as opposed to randomly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not exactly a noob - but almost :), I'm working on a JS based hangman game for an English teaching website. I've got everything working perfectly 'IF' I want the words to be selected randomly, but this unfortunately often means the same word will be repeated a few times in a row. So I'd like the words to appear in the order they appear in the array. I know this is  ridiculously simple but can't for the life of me to get this code to work:

```
var words = ['petrol', 'leaded', 'rate', 'crime', 'behalf'];

function chooseWord () {
var wordsLength = words.length;
for (var i = 0; i < wordsLength; i++) {
return words [wordsLength[i]];
}
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions/pointers

Many thanks

Terry

Comment: This will always select the first word, it will not be random, this doesnt work at all.

Comment: While that is the output he's going to get with this solution, he said he doesn't want it to be random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix... you're not indexing the array properly

```
var words = ['petrol', 'leaded', 'rate', 'crime', 'behalf'];

function chooseWord () {
   var wordsLength = words.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < wordsLength; i++) {
      return words[i];   // index using the 'i' value, not the word length
   }
}
```

however, since you return at each call to the function, this will get you the same word every time. Try something like this instead:

```
var words = ['petrol', 'leaded', 'rate', 'crime', 'behalf'];
var nextIndex = 0;

function chooseWord () {
   if ( nextIndex >= words.length ) {   // make sure it doesn't get higher than the length.
       nextIndex = 0;
   }
   nextIndex++;
   return words[nextIndex-1];
}
```

Test with:

```
alert(chooseWord());
alert(chooseWord());
alert(chooseWord());
alert(chooseWord());
```

Each time you call, you will get a new word. Example output using this test:

```
petrol
leaded
rate
crime
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but that's still repeatedly accessing only the first word in the array - I had tried that but it just keeps repeating 'petrol' rather than working its way through the array...

Comment: Ryan, you ARE the man!! :) thanks so much - unfortunately I can't vote you up as my rep isn't sufficient yet - but will do asap. You saved my bacon! :)

Comment: Simple problems get all of us at one point or another. Good luck!

Comment: You may not be able to upvote, but you can 'accept' his answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks Scott, that dawned on me a couple of seconds after commenting -doh!